# how to pass data using modal presented view controller to parent view controller upon dismiss?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UITextField` which has to get data from another `UITableViewController` that is presented on click of textfield. When I try to dismiss that `UITableViewController` in didselect row of index path.It doesnot show that selected row on `parentViewController`. Could somebody help..?

Comment: First, please give more context i and probably other cant help without any code

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        selectedObject=dataArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as NSString;
        println("selectedObjecttttttttttjjjdjddd\(selectedObject)");
        
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        
    }

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understood the question correctly. But in general the idea is to set up a delegate for presented view controller and send your data to it just before dismiss action. In case of modal presentation there's a property called `presentingViewController` that you can use for that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     //pass your data to parent controller here.
    [self.presentingViewController passData:data];

    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Of course you have to set up a property or a method in your parent controller to actually accept the data.